# Am i supposed to use WP tookit for WP8 development?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to WP 8 development. I want to add a Toggle switch to my application. However, I am not able to find the control in VS 2012 Toolbox.

A bit of Googling brought me to [this](https://nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit) WP 8 Toolkit Nuget package. Is the Toggle switch control used in WP 8 OS not available to developers directly? Do i have to use this toolkit only ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735581(v=vs.105).aspx

Yes. We need to use WP Toolkit.